# VC++ prerequisite according to paltform target into single installer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, prerequisites

I am having an .NET 4.0 application which needs VC++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed. While creating Setup Project using Visual Studio Installer project I have selected `Visual c++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x64)` and `Visual c++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)` to support on both 32bit and 64bit platforms.

While testing installer on 32bit machine it gives error

> Prerequisite check for system component Visual C++ 2010 Runtime
>   Libraries (x64) failed with the following error message: "Installation
>   of Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x64) is supported only on x64
>   machines."

How can I make Visual c++ 2010 Runtime Libraries Prerequisite conditional according to platform target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, if the VC redist package won't let you. The reason is that different architectures require separate MSI setups:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

So if you are really building an app and setup that is intended for both 32 and 64 bit then you build two setups, an x86 one with the x86 VC redist for 32-bit and an x64 one with the redist for 64-bit. You can add a condition to prevent the x86 setup from installing on x64, referring clients to the x64 setup.

Comment: Or can I make one setup with platform target x86 with x86 VC redist as prerequsite. AS currently my all projects platform target is set to `x86` only. So if setup is being executed on 64bit machine then x86 VC redist get installed.Is it okay?

Comment: If you make all your code x86 then yes, all you need is an x86 setup with the x86 redist. That all just works.

Comment: Yes!! I have done setup using [Procedures for deploying Visual C++ library DLLs as shared assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms235317%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) All is working perfect. :)